# Running Multiple exe files using Rstudio

Tags: r

I have exe file which was built on C++. The exe file needs an input argument. 
Now i want to launch multiple exe file from Rstudio by changing the input arguments so that i can run different scenarios in parallel. When i use system/shell/system2 commands, the model starts running inside the Rstudio environment itself, but i want to make it to run outside Rstudio environment, so that i can run multiple models at a time.

```
system("xyz.exe scenario1")

system("xyz.exe scenario2")

system("xyz.exe scenario3")
```

Comment: `lapply(paste0("xyz.exe scenario", 1:3), system)` ?

Comment: Does the `wait=FALSE` argument to system do what you're after?

Comment: Yes. That is what i was looking for. Thank you @Miff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `?system` you can see that there is an argument `wait`. Quoting from the help file:

> [`wait` is] a logical (not `NA`) indicating whether the R interpreter should wait
>   for the command to finish, or run it asynchronously. This will be
>   ignored (and the interpreter will always wait) if `intern = TRUE`.

So using `wait=TRUE` would cause the behaviour that you require.